# RichTextBox insert

Tags: c#, insert, richtextbox

I have a richtextbox that works. But I want to make a button in the toolbar(where you can edit the richtextbox) to insert a piece of text ( the text will be: " {...} ").

What did i do already:

I made a button in the toolbar. Now is my question: how do you insert this string on the place where the cursor stands?

thanks

Comment: By RichTextEditor, do you mean: <http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/sites/rich-text-editor/>? It pays to be explicit with ALL non-standard controls. Which version? Also, sadly, you're not likely to get much help with such a "specialised question" on a general programming forum. Mailing lists for the specific product are generally more fruitful. It'd be nice IF SOF was the perferred Q&A platform for ALL programming fields; but it isn't (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the selected text using the [SelectedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedtext.aspx). That does mean that when there is a selection it is overriden, but I'm sure if you want to simply insert you can move the caret first.

Edit: I assumed you meant RichTextBox here. Sorry if that's not what you meant.

Comment: yeah I meant the richtextbox in xaml.. But how do you know where the cursor stands?

Comment: @Stef, You use the [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx) property. At first glance (without testing) you can remove the selection by using the [SelectionLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionlength.aspx) property.